# Filter a .wav file using a low-pass filter in c

Tags: c, audio, filter, signal-processing

I have an assignment to create a C program that opens a.wav file, filter the audio file using an low-pass or high-pass filter and save the result in another file. For now I just opened the .wav file and display all the information from the header of the file. Can someone help me create a filter for the file?

Here is my code:

wave.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "wave.h"

 int main()
 {
    FILE *fp = NULL;
    FILE *outfile = fopen("filtered.wav", "wb");
    
     Wav wav;
     RIFF_t riff;
     FMT_t fmt;
     Data_t data;
 
     fp = fopen("sample.wav", "rb");

     if (!fp) {
         printf("can't open audio file\n");
         exit(1);
     }
 
     fread(&wav, 1, sizeof(wav), fp);
     
     riff = wav.riff;
     fmt = wav.fmt;
     data = wav.data;
 
     printf("ChunkID \t%c%c%c%c\n", riff.ChunkID[0], riff.ChunkID[1], riff.ChunkID[2], riff.ChunkID[3]);
     printf("ChunkSize \t%d\n", riff.ChunkSize);
     printf("Format \t\t%c%c%c%c\n", riff.Format[0], riff.Format[1], riff.Format[2], riff.Format[3]);
     
     printf("\n");
     
     printf("Subchunk1ID \t%c%c%c%c\n", fmt.Subchunk1ID[0], fmt.Subchunk1ID[1], fmt.Subchunk1ID[2], fmt.Subchunk1ID[3]);
     printf("Subchunk1Size \t%d\n", fmt.Subchunk1Size);
     printf("AudioFormat \t%d\n", fmt.AudioFormat);
     printf("NumChannels \t%d\n", fmt.NumChannels);
     printf("SampleRate \t%d\n", fmt.SampleRate);
     printf("ByteRate \t%d\n", fmt.ByteRate);
     printf("BlockAlign \t%d\n", fmt.BlockAlign);
     printf("BitsPerSample \t%d\n", fmt.BitsPerSample);
     
     printf("\n");
 
     printf("blockID \t%c%c%c%c\n", data.Subchunk2ID[0], data.Subchunk2ID[1], data.Subchunk2ID[2], data.Subchunk2ID[3]);
     printf("blockSize \t%d\n", data.Subchunk2Size);
     
     printf("\n");
    
     printf("duration \t%d\n", data.Subchunk2Size / fmt.ByteRate);
 }
```

wave.h

```
typedef struct WAV_RIFF {
    /* chunk "riff" */
    char ChunkID[4];   /* "RIFF" */
    /* sub-chunk-size */
    uint32_t ChunkSize; /* 36 + Subchunk2Size */
    /* sub-chunk-data */
    char Format[4];    /* "WAVE" */
} RIFF_t;

typedef struct WAV_FMT {
    /* sub-chunk "fmt" */
    char Subchunk1ID[4];   /* "fmt " */
    /* sub-chunk-size */
    uint32_t Subchunk1Size; /* 16 for PCM */
    /* sub-chunk-data */
    uint16_t AudioFormat;   /* PCM = 1*/
    uint16_t NumChannels;   /* Mono = 1, Stereo = 2, etc. */
    uint32_t SampleRate;    /* 8000, 44100, etc. */
    uint32_t ByteRate;  /* = SampleRate * NumChannels * BitsPerSample/8 */
    uint16_t BlockAlign;    /* = NumChannels * BitsPerSample/8 */
    uint16_t BitsPerSample; /* 8bits, 16bits, etc. */
} FMT_t;

typedef struct WAV_data {
    /* sub-chunk "data" */
    char Subchunk2ID[4];   /* "data" */
    /* sub-chunk-size */
    uint32_t Subchunk2Size; /* data size */
    /* sub-chunk-data */
    /* Data_block_t block; */
} Data_t;

/* typedef struct WAV_data_block {
} Data_block_t; */

typedef struct WAV_fotmat {
   RIFF_t riff;
   FMT_t fmt;
   Data_t data;
} Wav;
```

So I tried to open the file, store it in a buffer and filter it using the formula for the simplest low pass filter and store in another buffer. How can I write the out buffer in the output file?

```
int nb;
    int buffIn[1024];
    int buffOut[1024];
    fread( buffIn, sizeof(char), 100, fp);

    //I read all data in a buffer, copy the first 44 bytes(header) and filtered the rest of it
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < sizeof(buffIn); ++i)
    {
        if(i < 44){
            buffOut[i] = buffIn[i];
        }else{
            buffOut[i] = buffIn[i] + buffIn[i-1];
            printf("0x%02x",buffOut[x]);
            printf("\t");
        };
    }
```

Comment: I work as a frontend developer and I don't know much about C or signal processing. I just want to see how the filtering is made and try to understand it...

Comment: Cool, but Stack Overflow isn't really a code writing service, it's a curated collection of questions and answers designed to help future readers. You might have better luck and learn more if you read a tutorial (such as this arbitrary one from google: https://www.dsprelated.com/freebooks/filters/Simplest_Lowpass_Filter_I.html) and then return with a _specific_ question if you get stuck

Comment: I saw how can i low-pass filter an array of data but i can't understand how can i filter this audio file

Comment: Well your assignment will most likely be a single channel audio file, so given that, you've already read all of the header in and just need to read the audio data (the number of bytes of data is given by `Subchunk2Size`, I found [this resource](http://soundfile.sapp.org/doc/WaveFormat/) helpful for opening wav files, if a bit ugly to look at) into an array, and that's what you filter. Then write it back to a file.

Comment: So think about how to read the file into an array of data and then low-pass filter it and then write the array of data into a file. You did read the header. How will you read the data? You did read the header for the data block. The rest of the file after that is the actual data.

Comment: If you are feeling particularly clever, it's even possible to do this *without* storing the whole file in an array at once, to use less memory

Comment: So I tried to open the file, store it in a buffer and filter it using the formula for the simplest low pass filter and store in another buffer. How can i write the out buffer in the output file? I put the code in the question

Answer (score 0):

I came up with the following code but i can't figure out what i did wrong:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "wave.h"

 int main()
 {
    FILE *fp = NULL;
    FILE *outfile = NULL;
    
     Wav wav;
     RIFF_t riff;
     FMT_t fmt;
     Data_t data;
 
     fp = fopen("3sec.wav", "rb");
     outfile = fopen("filtered.wav", "wb");

     if(!fp) {
         printf("can't open audio file\n");
         exit(1);
     }

 
     fread(&wav, 1, sizeof(wav), fp);

     riff = wav.riff;
     fmt = wav.fmt;
     data = wav.data;
 
     printf("ChunkID \t%c%c%c%c\n", riff.ChunkID[0], riff.ChunkID[1], riff.ChunkID[2], riff.ChunkID[3]);
     printf("ChunkSize \t%d\n", riff.ChunkSize);
     printf("Format \t\t%c%c%c%c\n", riff.Format[0], riff.Format[1], riff.Format[2], riff.Format[3]);
     
     printf("\n");
     
     printf("Subchunk1ID \t%c%c%c%c\n", fmt.Subchunk1ID[0], fmt.Subchunk1ID[1], fmt.Subchunk1ID[2], fmt.Subchunk1ID[3]);
     printf("Subchunk1Size \t%d\n", fmt.Subchunk1Size);
     printf("AudioFormat \t%d\n", fmt.AudioFormat);
     printf("NumChannels \t%d\n", fmt.NumChannels);
     printf("SampleRate \t%d\n", fmt.SampleRate);
     printf("ByteRate \t%d\n", fmt.ByteRate);
     printf("BlockAlign \t%d\n", fmt.BlockAlign);
     printf("BitsPerSample \t%d\n", fmt.BitsPerSample);
     
     printf("\n");
 
     printf("blockID \t%c%c%c%c\n", data.Subchunk2ID[0], data.Subchunk2ID[1], data.Subchunk2ID[2], data.Subchunk2ID[3]);
     printf("blockSize \t%d\n", data.Subchunk2Size);
     
     printf("\n");
    
     printf("duration \t%d\n", data.Subchunk2Size / fmt.ByteRate);

    int nb;
    int buffIn[1024];
    int buffOut[1024];
    fread( buffIn, sizeof(char), 1, fp);

    //I read all data in a buffer, copy the first 44 bytes(header) and filtered the rest of it
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < sizeof(buffIn); ++i)
    {
        if(i < 44){
            buffOut[i] = buffIn[i];
        }else{
            buffOut[i] = buffIn[i] + buffIn[i-1];
            printf("0x%02x",buffOut[i]);
            printf("\t");
        };
    }
    fwrite(buffOut , 1 , sizeof(char) , outfile );

 }
```

Comment: Try to ask questions or queries to the author in the comment section instead of asking in the answer post itself.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.